# Select the image onclick and apply seekbar resize to it

Tags: java, android

In my app i have to apply resize using seekbar to selected image onclick but problem is that only last applied stickerview can be resized and if i want to resize the previous stickerview then also last sticker is being resized.
Can anyone help me with this problem

```
holder.icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (a == 1) {


                    canvas.setBackgroundResource(mThumbIds[position]);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    a = 0;

                }
                if (a1 == 1) {
                    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
                    gallery.setSpacing(1);
                    final GalleryImageAdapter galleryImageAdapter= new GalleryImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(),position);
                    gallery.setAdapter(galleryImageAdapter);


                    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                            iv_sticker1 = new StickerImageView(MainActivity2.this);
                            if(x ==1)
                            iv_sticker1.setImageResource(galleryImageAdapter.mImageIds[position]);
                            if(x ==2)
                                iv_sticker1.setImageResource(galleryImageAdapter.mImageIds1[position]);
                            if(x ==3)
                                iv_sticker1.setImageResource(galleryImageAdapter.mImageIds2[position]);
                            canvas.addView(iv_sticker1);
                        }
                    });


                    a1 = 0;

                }
                if (a2 == 1) {
                    iv_sticker1 = new StickerImageView(MainActivity2.this);
                    iv_sticker1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(mThumbIds2[position]));
                    canvas.addView(iv_sticker1);
                    iv_sticker1.setOwnerId(2);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    a2 = 0;
                }
                if (a3 == 1) {
                    iv_sticker1 = new StickerImageView(MainActivity2.this);
                    iv_sticker1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(mThumbIds3[position]));
                    canvas.addView(iv_sticker1);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    a3 = 0;
                }
            }
        });
```

And this is my resize program

```
final SeekBar sk1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    sk1.setMax(500);
    sk1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            iv_sticker1.getMainView();
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(progress, progress);
            iv_sticker1.setLayoutParams(params);

            iv_sticker1.setMinimumWidth(progress);
            iv_sticker1.setMinimumHeight(progress);


        }
    });
```

Now whenever i do this only last iv_sticker1 get selected.How can i apply resize to selected image on click?